# Fluid width not working

Tags: html, css

I'm using two css files [for my fluid width site here][1]: one where the left hand nav is 'display:none' when below a certain width.

I'm setting the right hand nav (with banners) to max-width:348px and a padding-left:20px.

The problem happens when I set the #main-content div to a percentage width: it doesn't resize correctly and causes it to drop down below the right nav when the window's reduced. It doesn't really make sense so not sure how the best way to go about it is.

Within the #main-content div, there is the #left-nav and #middle divs which are floated left and I've specified max-widths and padding.

When the window is below a certain width I'll remove the left nav with display:none, but until then I'd like the #main-content width to be fluid.

The left nav also needs to be a specific width to ensure the list items stay on one line.

Hope someone can help; it's probably something simple, but just can't make it to work..

Here's the **CSS**:

```css
.right-nav {
  padding:0 0 0 20px;
  margin:0;float:right;
  width:348px;
}
#main-content {
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  border-botom:0;
  box-shadow: 0px -1px 18px #e0e0e0;
  margin-top:-2px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
  float:left;
  width:70.2%;
  background-color:#fff;
  height:100%;
  float:left;
  padding:30px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
}
#left-nav {
  float:left;
  width:20.5%;
  padding:15px 0 5px 20px;
  background-color:#fff;
  color:#888;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}
#middle {
  width:72.3%;
  background-color:#fff;
  height:100%;
  float:left;
  margin:0 21px 5px;
}
```

error page: [here](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's to do with the margins on your #middle element. Your widths are percentages but your margins are absolute values.

To give you an example, when you reduce the screen size down so `#main-content` is 824px wide, you end up with;

`#left-nav`: 20.5% = 168.92px plus  padding-left = 20px;

`#middle`: 72.3% = 595.72px plus margin = 42px (21px either side)

Total = 828px and therefore #middle has to drop down below #left-nav

So it's a case of either reducing the percentages, making the margins percentages or adding a new @media screen style for those smaller widths.

*EDIT based on comments.

It's the same thing going on again - you're `.right-nav` element has a fixed width of 348px, the `#main-content` has a max-width of 67% but absolute padding of 20px either side;

So if the whole `#content-wrapper` has a width of 1069px you have;

`.right-nav`: 348px

`#main-content` =  716px; padding: 40px (20px left and 20px right).

Total = 1104px and the #main-content drops down.  It's the mix of relative(%s) and absolute(pixels) that's causing the issues.

Comment: Have updated answer to reflect comments, hope this helps.  By the way, are you using Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug?  You can just turn CSS properties on and off using these tools to see what is causing the problems.

Comment: You could do - there's no problem with mixing them up as such, I do it all the time. I was really just making you aware that's what was causing the problem. You could just reduce the %s of the main containers a bit, plus I see you are using @media screen already so you could add another breakpoint and reduce the padding down to a smaller fixed amount on slightly smaller screen.s

Comment: I changed #middle to have a width of 70.2% rather than 71.2% in 1024res.css line 11 and it looks fine.

In Structure.css line 96 reduce the width by 1% again to 71.3% and it works well too

Comment: Lol, no worries!  Exactly as it is right now but dropping 1% as I've said in the last comment seems to be working fine, try that first.